# Waiting for a call function to finish before iterating forward

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am in a bit of a bind here regarding a code I have to write. 
At the moment I am trying to iterate through an array of strings. After a certain text is found, if a value is true, the value is bound to a temporaryObject.img. After that a call has to be made to the server in order for some information to be retrieved and to be bound to the same temporaryObject as a second property (temporaryObject.url). Unfortunately, the call is resolved probably after the iteration is done because it does not add this add the url from the call to the server in the Object. The libraries I am using are angularjs and jquery.

Here is a part of the code I wrote.

```
$scope.Data = [];
var strArray = ["img1", "link", "img2", "link2", "img3", "link3"];
var re1 = /<img/;
for(var i = 0 ; i < strArray.length ; i++) {
    var tempObject = {};
    var test = re1.test(strArray[i]);
    if (test){
    tempObject.img = strArray[i + 1];
    myAngularService.getServerInformation().then(function(result){
        tempObject.url = result;
        $scope.Data.push(tempObject);
    }
   }
```

Unfortunately, the information from the server does not arrive in the same time as the iteration is done or something goes wrong since $scope.Data will not contain the url requested from the server. Any suggestions as how to use maybe a promise for this kind of code would be appreciated. I tried searching every possible solution but with no avail.

Comment: You have to wait for ALL your calls made from that loop to finish before you can use your $scope.Data. Additionally since response times can differ, the objects you push into $scope.Data may not be in the same order as you issued the calls to the server. Is that what you want?

Comment: Because of closure, your callbacks are all referencing the same `tempObject`.

Comment: Indeed, the responses may differ, however the arguments with which the calls are made are responding with a certain data and a certain key which I take and make them to be in order. I have not included this in the code since there is much to write in regards to how I use the data.

Comment: Should I use different variables for each server response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is function-scoped. In other words:

```
if (true) {
    var testing = 5;
}
console.log(testing); // Logs 5
```

Applying this to your example, `tempObject` in your `.then` callback function are all referencing the same variable!

One solution is to use an Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) inside your for statement to create a new scope:

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < strArray.length ; i++) {
    (function() {
        var tempObject = {}; // Is now declared within the new function
        /* ... code here ... */
    })();
}
```

Another solution is to simply use [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) (or [angular.forEach](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach)):

```
$.each(strArray, function(index, value) {
    var tempObject = {}; // Is now declared within the new function
    /* ... code here ... */
});
```

Regarding waiting for all your calls to finish, one solution is to store your promises in an array use angular's [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) service:

```
$scope.Data = [];
var promises = [];
var strArray = ["img1", "link", "img2", "link2", "img3", "link3"];
var re1 = /img/;
$.each(strArray, function (index, value) {
    var tempObject = {};
    var test = re1.test(value);
    if (test) {
        tempObject.img = strArray[index + 1];

        var myPromise = myAngularService.getServerInformation();

        myPromise.then(function (result) {
            tempObject.url = result;
            $scope.Data.push(tempObject);
        }

        promises.push(myPromise);
    }
})

$q.all(promises).then(function() {
    // All calls will have finished
    console.log($scope.Data); 
}, function() {
    // At least 1 call failed!
    console.log("an error occurred!");
});
```

Comment: Very nice answer! Another option instead of $.each or an IIFE would be to define a secondary function where you pass the tempObject in and which does the getServerInformation() call. Then each tempObject would be in correct scope as well. That's how I did something like this by now - would you consider this practice not as good or just different?

Comment: @user2415266 That solution is good as well - and probably more readable in certain cases.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this thoroughly. It did the trick. I also have a more in-depth example on how to use this in the future. Thank you so much.